# How to access application.properties values in constructor

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to use `@ConfigurationProperties` to load `key-value` pairs from `application.properties` file.

application.properties

```
soap.action.segalRead=Segal/SegalRead
soap.action.mantilUpdate=Mantil/MantilUpdate
```

SoapUri.java

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "soap.action")
public class SoapUri {

    @NotNull
    private String segalRead;
    @NotNull
    private String mantilUpdate;

    //getters and setters
}
```

SoapUriTests.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SoapUriTests {

    @Autowired 
    private SoapUri soapUri;

    @Test
    public void testSoapUri_returnsSoapAction() {
        assertThat(soapUri.getSegalRead()).isEqualTo("Segal/SegalRead");
        assertThat(soapUri.getMantilUpdate()).isEqualTo("Mantil/MantilUpdate");
    }
}
```

Above unit test works great.

However, I need to use `SoapUri` in real code.
Consider following code:

```
public class MantilUpdateReadVO extends RequestClientVO {

    @Autowired
    private SoapUri soapUri;

    public MantilUpdateReadVO(final MantilUpdate mantilUpdate) {
        super(mantilUpdate, soapUri.getMantilUpdate(), MantilUpdateResponse.class);
    }
}
public class RequestClientVO {

    private Object readRequest;
    private String serviceName;
    private Class<?> unmarshalTargetclass;

    public MwsRequestClientVO(Object readRequest, String serviceName, Class<?> unmarshalTargetclass) {
        super();
        this.readRequest = readRequest;
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
        this.unmarshalTargetclass = unmarshalTargetclass;
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

Above complains about: "*Cannot refer to an instance field soapUri while explicitly invoking a constructor*"

Does anyone know a workaround for injecting `segalRead` and `mantilUpdate` in `constructor` of `super()`

Comment: Assuming MantilUpdateReadVO is indeed a Spring bean (if not, Spring will never inject anything in it), then add SoapUri as a constructor argument, and remove the useless field.

Comment: @JBNizet I tried passing new SoapUri().getMantilUpdate() as constructor argument but it is null.

Comment: `MantilUpdateReadVO`,`MantilUpdate`,`RequestClientVO` are spring beans?

Answer (score 1):

You are using field-injection, which is not a good idea. See Oliver Gierke's [Why Field Injection is Evil](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/) for details.

The field cannot be injected until after the instance is constructed; so, you cannot use an injected field during construction.

Change the code like this:

```java
    @Autowired
    public MantilUpdateReadVO(final SoapUri soapUri, final MantilUpdate mantilUpdate) {
        super(mantilUpdate, soapUri.getMantilUpdate(), MantilUpdateResponse.class);
    }
```

You also need to ensure `MantilUpdateReadVO` is a Spring Bean; might need to add `@Component`.

Good luck!